# Updating gradle version from 2.2.3 to 3.0.1 breaks react-native-mailcore library

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, mailcore2

I build [react-native-mailcore](https://github.com/agenthunt/react-native-mailcore) example app successfully, which uses [native mailcore2](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2). When i update gradle version from 2.2.3 to 3.0.1, build succeeds, but in the runtime,when code:

```
 SMTPSession smtpSession = new SMTPSession();
```

is called, the following error is occurred:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz" referenced by "/data/app/com.inkotrack-2/lib/x86/libMailCore.so"...
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
at com.libmailcore.MainThreadUtils.(MainThreadUtils.java:19)
at com.libmailcore.MainThreadUtils.(MainThreadUtils.java:9)
at com.libmailcore.MainThreadUtils.singleton(MainThreadUtils.java:14)
at com.libmailcore.NativeObject.(NativeObject.java:42)
at com.reactlibrary.RNMailCoreModule$1.run(RNMailCoreModule.java:41)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```